# Removing textfield rounded background in SwiftUI watchKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, watchkit

Is there any possible way to remove rounded gray background in watchkit's Textfield (SwiftUI) ? I tried to add `.textFieldStyle(.plain)` but still the background is visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove the rounded background of a text field in SwiftUI, you can use the .background() modifier with a custom shape to draw a rectangle instead of the default rounded rectangle.

here is the sample code..

```
TextField("Enter text here", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(5.0)
                )
```

Comment: Still has color, even if I set it to `.black` I just need to be totally clear